# How to assign a text value to a label in a gridview on button click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to assign a value to a label in a gridview on button click. For some reason, my code below does not seem to work.

Gridview cell that should be changed on click (the label should show "Pending"):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' />        
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Button that triggers the change:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnUpdate" text="Update" OnClientClick="changeStat()" />
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeStat() {

        var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvAUTSubscription.ClientID%>");

        for (var j = 0; j < grid.rows.length - 1; j++) {
            grid.rows[j].cells[3].children[0].innerText = "Pending";
        }
    }; 
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: grid.rows[j].cells[3].children[0].set_text('Pending');

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'set_text' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @icehaven debug and see if you are getting a property like value, or other wise grid.rows[j].cells[3].children[0].html = "pending"; this should work

Comment: I just found out that this line:
grid.rows[j+1].cells[3].childNodes[1].innerText = "Pending";
actually works. It's just that the labels got cleared up on postback and i dont know why it happens, no wonder i think the script doesn't work.

Comment: @Rex neither "set_text" nor "html" are properties of DOM elements.

Comment: @iceheaven31 when the POST happens, the page is refreshed from the server.